# Changing menubar background colour in MFC dialog

Tags: colors, menu, mfc, dialog

I would like to change the colour of the whole menu bar. I've found a few posts on this subject but none has helped me so far. In particular I would like to use something like this simple snippet:

```
    MENUINFO MenuInfo = {0};
    MenuInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MenuInfo);
    MenuInfo.hbrBack = *NewBrush; // Brush you want to draw
    MenuInfo.fMask = MIM_BACKGROUND;
    MenuInfo.dwStyle = MNS_AUTODISMISS;
    MenuInfo.cyMax = 25;

    CMenu* pMenu = GetMenu();
    HMENU mh = pMenu->GetSafeHmenu();
    if(IsMenu(pMenu->m_hMenu))
    {
        SetMenuInfo(mh, &MenuInfo);
    }
```

But `GetMenu` doesn't seem to work. Is that something to do with window being a dialog? I've tried calling it in `OnInitDialog` and `OnCreate`.

Comment: I think you should have a look on the MFC Feature Pack `CMFCMenuBar` class.

Answer (score 0):

In order to customize your `CMenu` you need to use `MF_OWNERDRAW` style. Basically you need to handle `WM_MEASUREITEM` and `WM_DRAWITEM` messages to implement the required functionality.

Comment: Thanks for that. I found this page which seems to use the method you suggest:

Comment: Sorry, hit return. as I was saying, I found this page which seems to use the method you suggest: [link](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/menu/article.php/c3721/Create-an-Owner-Draw-Menu--Step-by-Step.htm) but as well as being very involved, only seems to colour the head of each menu entry, not the whole menu bar.